# Sorting custom dates in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a hash with keys being dates:

```
my %dates = (
'May 13, 2015' => 8,
'May 7, 2015' => 1,
'Apr 29, 2015' => 2,
'May 12, 2015' => 1,
'Apr 16, 2015' => 13,
'May 6, 2015' => 1,
);
```

I'm trying to sort them by date. I've tried two ways:

```
foreach my $k (sort {join('', (split ' ', $a)[2,0,1]) <=> join('', (split ' ', $a)[2,0,1])} keys(%dates)) 
{ print $k . " = " . $dates{$k}; }
```

which doesn't work since the month is a string, and this:

```
foreach my $k (sort {join('', (split ' ', $a)[2,0,1]) cmp join('', (split ' ', $a)[2,0,1])} keys(%dates)) 
{ print $k . " = " . $dates{$k}; }
```

doesn't work either, it just puts all the Apr first then May. Anyone has an idea on how to fix it?

Comment: How about actually parsing them as dates?

Comment: I want to avoid having to use DateTime. Is there a way to nest the three parts inside of the `{ }` of that `sort`?

Comment: Don't post code with syntax errors.

Comment: Yes. Any function can be used in `sort` provided it returns a positional value like `cmp` or `<=>` do: `-1`, `0` or `1`. But really - use a module, because parsing dates is painful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can parse the dates using [Time::Piece](http://perltricks.com/article/59/2014/1/10/Solve-almost-any-datetime-need-with-Time--Piece)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

my %dates = (
    'May 13, 2015' => 8,
    'May 7, 2015' => 1,
    'Apr 29, 2015' => 2,
    'May 12, 2015' => 1,
    'Apr 16, 2015' => 13,
    'May 6, 2015' => 1,
);

for my $k (sort by_date keys %dates) {
    print "$k => $dates{$k}\n";
}

sub by_date {
    my ($ta, $tb) = map Time::Piece->strptime($_, '%b %d, %Y'), $a, $b;
    $ta <=> $tb;
}
```

Output:

```
Apr 16, 2015 => 13
Apr 29, 2015 => 2 
May 6, 2015 => 1  
May 7, 2015 => 1  
May 12, 2015 => 1 
May 13, 2015 => 8
```

Of course, if you wanted to give up the benefits of [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Pieces), you could do something along the following lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

my %dates = (
    'May 13, 2015' => 8,
    'May 7, 2015' => 1,
    'Apr 29, 2015' => 2,
    'May 12, 2015' => 1,
    'Apr 16, 2015' => 13,
    'May 6, 2015' => 1,
);

for my $k (sort by_ugliness keys %dates) {
    print "$k => $dates{$k}\n";
}

sub by_ugliness {
    state $months = {
        do {
            my $i = 1;
            map {$_ => $i++}
            qw(Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec)
        }
    };

    my ($ta, $tb) = map [
        /\A (\S+) \s+ ([0-9]{1,2}), \s+ ([0-9]{4})\z/x
    ], $a, $b;

    ($ta->[2] <=> $tb->[2]) ||
    ($months->{ $ta->[0] } <=> $months->{ $tb->[0]}) ||
    ($ta->[1] <=> $tb->[1]) ;
}
```

At some point, you are going to start refining that pattern match. Don't ;-)

Comment: The current `Time::Piece` (v1.29) has its own `strptime` which is copied from *FreeBSD* and works fine here. But older versions try to use the native C library and cannot be relied on to cope with single-digit day fields

Comment: ***"that pattern match"*** is way over-complicated given that you don't handle the case where it doesn't match. *Either* you choose to trust the incoming data and all you need is `/\w+/g` *or* you need to write something that behaves sensibly if the data isn't up to scratch instead of leaving you scraping up roadkill

Answer (score 2):

What you think of as dates, aren't: They are strings. You can't do what you're trying to do like that. First you have to turn them into *dates*.

Perl has a nice module for this in the form of [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece).

```
my $date = Time::Piece -> strptime ( 'May 13, 2015', '%b %d, %Y' );
print $date;
```

So to do your sort you would want:

```
my %dates = (
    'May 13, 2015' => 8,
    'May 7, 2015'  => 1,
    'Apr 29, 2015' => 2,
    'May 12, 2015' => 1,
    'Apr 16, 2015' => 13,
    'May 6, 2015'  => 1,
);


foreach my $key (
    sort {
        Time::Piece->strptime( $a, '%b %d, %Y' )
            <=> Time::Piece->strptime( $b, '%b %d, %Y' )
    } keys %dates
    )
{
    print "$key, $dates{$key}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was going to post exactly what *Sinan Ünür* has written, so here is an alternative solution in case it may be of use to anyone.

This uses a custom [*Schwartzian Transform*](http://www.stonehenge.com/merlyn/UnixReview/col64.html) that compares each of the three date fields, with a hash `%months` that converts month names into numbers

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my %dates = (
  'May 13, 2015' => 8,
  'May 7, 2015' => 1,
  'Apr 29, 2015' => 2,
  'May 12, 2015' => 1,
  'Apr 16, 2015' => 13,
  'May 6, 2015' => 1,
);

my %months = do {
  my $m = 0;
  map { $_ => ++$m } qw/ Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec /;
};

my @sorted =
    map  { $_->[0] }
    sort {
        $a->[3] <=> $b->[3] or
        $months{$a->[1]} <=> $months{$b->[1]} or
        $a->[2] <=> $b->[2]
    }
    map  { [ $_, /\w+/g ] } keys %dates;

say for @sorted;
```

**output**

```
Apr 16, 2015
Apr 29, 2015
May 6, 2015
May 7, 2015
May 12, 2015
May 13, 2015
```

Comment: See also: List::UtilsBy::sort_by. That would neaten up your inner sort function no end...

Comment: @LeoNerd: Yes I thought of that. But it would be counter-productive to post a solution that required your `List::UtilsBy` *instead of* `Time::Piece`. Get it into core and I'll think again

Comment: It's not instead of the `Time::Piece`; it's instead of the hacky manual Schwartzian sort. And given the ease with which the entire CPAN toolchain lets users install new modules, I really don't find the core/noncore distinction to be of interest.

Comment: @LeoNerd: Regarding CPAN, there are genuine situations where it is impossible to build a module on the target machine -- web servers for instance. In the case of your module, that can be bypassed by copying the .pm into place, but that isn't part of the tool chain. More important is the case where people are prohibited by bureaucracy or even a simple *belief* that they cannot employ third-party code. This is nonsense of course, but it is as effective as a practical impediment

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative that does not require an additional module:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my %dates = (
    'May 13, 2015' => 8,
    'May 7, 2015' => 1,
    'Apr 29, 2015' => 2,
    'May 12, 2015' => 1,
    'Apr 16, 2015' => 13,
    'May 6, 2015' => 1,
);

my $i = 1;
my %month_map = map { $_ => $i++ } qw(Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec);

my @dates = map { "$_->[0] => $dates{$_->[0]}" }
            sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
            map { [$_, date_to_number($_) ]} keys %dates;

for my $d ( @dates ) {
    say $d;
}

sub date_to_number {
    my $date_str = shift;
    if ( $date_str =~ m/^([^\s]{3})\s([^,]+),\s(\d{4})$/ ) {
         return $3 . ${\(length($month_map{$1}) == 1 ? '0' . $month_map{$1} : $month_map{$1})} . ${\(length($2) == 1 ? '0' . $2 : $2)};
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output will do the following:

```
Apr 16, 2015 => 13
Apr 29, 2015 => 2
May 6, 2015 => 1
May 7, 2015 => 1
May 12, 2015 => 1
May 13, 2015 => 8
```